# How do you access the current RouteData from View in .net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routedata

If I want to directly access the `RouteData` (the current action or parameter values for example) from the `View`, rather than having to pass it in from the controller as part of the `ViewData`, what class would i use?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
this.ViewContext.RouteData
```

should do the trick.