# Get ID from querystring

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, view

url: WebsiteName/Player/Details/2

@Request.QueryString["id"]; is not working. but,

if the url is has been: WebsiteName/Player/Details?id=2 it is working.

Comment: Check your RouteConfig file.....

Comment: is it not possible Get ID as WebsiteName/Player/Details/2

Comment: From View you can access the id value by @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]. Source http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134864/1019435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url: WebsiteName/Player/Details/2

You can passing value this way. Then you can get value in controller using this line....

RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()